# Parsing XML and it is returning NaN instead of actual value?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to grab the value of the `MonthDataLoaded` tag and I want it to return `Apr`, but it's returning `NaN` when I alert the variable. If I grab the `YearDataLoaded` and alert it, it returns the correct value of `2018`. What gives?

**XML Result:**

```
<BMSHealthReport>

<Site>Ft. Belvoir</Site>

<TotalUnits>349</TotalUnits>

<PercentReporting>85.39 %</PercentReporting>

<PercentNotReporting>14.61 %</PercentNotReporting>

<PercentBypassed>0.29 %</PercentBypassed>

<NumberLogins>52</NumberLogins>

<NumberAlarms>871</NumberAlarms>

<TotalEnergySavings>22,498</TotalEnergySavings>

<MonthDataLoaded>Apr </MonthDataLoaded>

<YearDataLoaded>2018</YearDataLoaded>

</BMSHealthReport>
```

**How I am grabbing the particular value I want:**

```
monthLoaded = xml.responseXML.xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("BMSHealthReport").parseFloat(x[1].getElementsByTagName("MonthDataLoaded")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

alert(monthLoaded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse a string as a float, which returns `NaN` for non-number-like input. Remove the `parseFloat` call:

```
monthLoaded = xml.responseXML.xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BMSHealthReport")[0].getElementsByTagName("MonthDataLoaded")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Comment: Bucket - Thank you. I just love when it's something so easy and something I should figured out on my own.